# What git hooks can be executed on cherry-pick operation?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am trying to find a way to check commits when cherry-picking them. Unfortunately, I cannot find a git hook that works with `cherry-pick` operation. What would be a possible solution to execute a script on cherry-picked commit?

Comment: `prepare-commit-msg` is invoked for `git cherry-pick`(with out `-n`). But it seems impossible to distinguish `git cherry-pick` from other commands like `git rebase`.

Comment: @ElpieKay So 'pre-rebase' hook will be called on cherry-pick?

Comment: @ziemowit141 No. Then it's possible to distinguish `git cherry-pick` from `git rebase`.

Answer (score 3):

As the other told in the comments above, there is no direct cherry-pick hook.

But I can propose you a **workaround**, that could work under certain conditions:

Some git front-ends add a default commit message to every cherry-pick commit.

Here just as an example [GitExtension](http://gitextensions.github.io/) where a cherry pick command shows you a  dialogue called "Cherry pick commit" with a tickable option "Add commit reference to commit message".
With this option the commit message will look like e. g.:

```
Fix of security problem sp345

(cherry picked from commit c157f17740bad0c8c59ff3f693a747552008371d)

# Conflicts:
#   authorization/secure/check.py
```

A [commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook could be written doing this:

1. Checking if the commit message contains `cherry picked from commit`
2. if yes then do whatever you want to do in a "cherry pick hook"

There is only one condition required: That every committer follows the rule to add (via tool or manually) the text to the commit message that is needed to detect it properly as a cherry-picked commit.